# append function to add <li> with <ul> dynamically not working in android emulator,but works in browser's well

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile

append function to add list-item  with unordered /ordered list> dynamically not working in android emulator,but works in browser's well.
I tried to develop android app using html code.when running in browser,the code works perfectly.but fails when trying to integrate it with android emulator with eclipse

Thanks in advance
this is the html what i have tried followed by js

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview1" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">

</ul>

<script>
  var myvalues = new Array("123","345","5534");
  var ccab=myvalues.length; 
  for(row=1; row <= ccab; row++) {
    $("#listview1").append('<li><input type="radio" name="nutwork"id="radio'+row+'"value="radio'+row+'"/><label for="radio'+row+'">'+myvalues[row-1]+'</label></li>');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#listview").listview("refresh");` after appending items.

Comment: thanks Omar.., am so tired.i tried this already...no use.... :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/M8r9R/ `.checbkoxradio()` to create radio buttons.

Comment: @Omar...it is working well in all browsers...
But, Not showing any lists,when i tried to call this html file in eclipse to run in android emulator,while all other controls are displaying :(

Comment: make sure you bind it to `$(document).on("pageinit", function () { //code });` and place it inside page div if you're using _single page model_.

Answer (score 0):

You should use id of ul while appending:

Use:

```
$("#listview1").append('');
```

Instead Of

```
$("#listview").append('');
```

Comment: sorry ...itz my miztake.... i tried many things....and so put wrong code... i've used the id only there..,later changed like this...
no use :(